# How to close a Pop-Up while running RunApplication(X) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, popup, desktop-application

I am trying to run an Application, but during the running of this application, there is a pop-up, which makes the code freeze as I do not know how to close the pop-up.

The application is built on VB.NET

```
Dim oDesk as Object
Dim oApp as Object

oDesk =CreateObject("Desktop.Application") 
oApp = oDesk.RunApplication(Input1) 'Reference to the VB.NET code that will navigate to the required module.

SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

Tried to send ENTER to close the pop-up, but RunApplication gets, stuck. Not sure how to restrict pop-ups etc. in VB.net.
Any help appreciated!

Best, 
Gert

Comment: Is this an application that has some UI input, like for a user to interact with?

Answer (score 0):

You are able typically to create an additional object to handle the popUps. This is rather an application specific, so be careful. The logic depends on the application.

```
Dim oDesk as Object
Dim oApp as Object
Dim oAppPopUp as Object

oDesk =CreateObject("Desktop.Application") 
oApp = oDesk.RunApplication(Input1,oAppPopUp) 'Reference to the VB.NET code that will    navigate to the required module.

SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
```